# how to refresh only data in ajax?

Tags: ajax

here, when i m going to replace my div i want to refresh only data not whole html design at 7 line

```
function func_name(id_1,id_2)
{
    $.ajax({
        type :"GET",
        url:''<?php echo site_url('controller/function');?>/'+id_1+'/'+id_2,<br />
        success: function(data){
            $('#right').html(data); // id where do you want to replace div
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: If you copied this code from your site, it shouldn't work at all, you got your quotes messed up.

Comment: Also, please include a **precise** description of what you want your code to do and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh data, you'll need to define some HTML document element identifiers and set them one by one.

For example, in the `$.ajax` success callback, instead of calling `$('#right').html(data);`, if your `right` container has 2 spans to show first and second name of some user, you would do this:

```
$("#right #name").text(data.name);
$("#right #secondName").text(data.name);
```

...and your HTML should look as follows:

```
<div id="right">
   <span id="name"></span>
   <span id="secondName"></span>
</div>
```